# Lua- Test if two values are true

Tags: lua

I'm trying to test if either or two values are true. My code keeps expecting "then" after '!'.

```
if x != 0 or y != 0 then 
    player:doStuff(x, y)
end
```

Comment: You use the `{}` icon in the menu bar after selecting the text you want to mark as code.

Comment: lua doesn't use `!=` it uses `~=` as could be found with any number of searches online and by looking at any number of lua tutorials/introductions. Not to mention the official books and manuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Lua doco](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html):

> **3.4.4 – Relational Operators**
>
> Lua supports the following relational operators:
> `== : equality`
> `~= : inequality`
> `<  : less than`
> `>  : greater than`
> `<= : less or equal`
> `>= : greater or equal`

The following transcript shows both incorrect and correct way:

```
$ lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
>
> if 1 != 0 then
stdin:1: 'then' expected near '!'
>
> if 1 ~= 0 then
>> print "unequal"
>> end
unequal
>
```

Comment: Linking the lua 5.0 documentation is likely not the most approprate version to use.

Comment: @Etan, I'm still using 5.1 so the 5.0 docs didn't seem that distant to me, and the inequality operator goes back _at least_ to 2.0 :-). However, I've upgraded the link to the 5.3 version and modified the extract, thanks for the suggestion.